# Pictures aligned horizontally adjust in size with window size

Tags: html, css, image

I made a quick example of images aligned horizontally:

All of the images adjust to the height of the "wrap" div.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiE1z.png

Yet, when I make the window smaller, images start to come out of the div and go below as such:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yttA0.png

I want to make it so as I make the window smaller, the images get smaller. To fit horizontally in the size of the browser.
Here is the code used to make the existing page:

html:

```
<h1> Thriller </h1>

    <div id="week-wrap">
    <div id="sunday" class="day"><img src="http://www.allipadwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/tropical-island-ipad-wallpaper-500x500.jpg"></div>
    <div id="monday" class="day"><img src="http://mountains.insidrinfo.com/mountains-asia/Media/mountains-asia.jpg"></div>
    <div id="tuesday" class="day"><img src="http://s4.favim.com/orig/50/beautiful-city-light-night-street-Favim.com-460323.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin: 0 auto;}
#week-wrap {border: 1px solid #000; height: 300px;}
.day {float: left;}
img {height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `float: left` use `display: inline-block` for the divs.  Then, add `white-space: nowrap` to the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/uYTxW/

Comment: That partially fixes the problem, but not fully. I want all the image to be visible from within the current window size. So this would require the images to shrink as the window gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

try resizing image div with javascript on resize window:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){  //Adjusts image when browser resized  
    // do your image size logic here
    // $('#week-wrap').width(); // width of div container
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate removing the divs around each image.  You can style the images directly.  Also, instead of setting an explicit height on your wrapper, set overflow: hidden to establish a block formatting context so that it automatically expands to contain your floats.

You wind up with markup like:

```
<h1> Thriller </h1>

<div id="week-wrap">
    <img src="http://www.allipadwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/tropical-island-ipad-wallpaper-500x500.jpg" id="sunday" />
    <img src="http://mountains.insidrinfo.com/mountains-asia/Media/mountains-asia.jpg" id="monday" />
    <img src="http://s4.favim.com/orig/50/beautiful-city-light-night-street-Favim.com-460323.jpg" id="tuesday" />
</div>
```

and CSS like:

```
body{margin: 0 auto;}
#week-wrap {border: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; }
#week-wrap > img { width: 33.333%; height: auto; float: left;}
```

with this result: http://jsfiddle.net/4Aytd/

```
var imageSizer = function () {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('#week-wrap > img'),
        numImages = images.length,
        imageWidth = (100/numImages) + '%',
        i;
    for(i = numImages-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        images[i].style.width = imageWidth;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Aytd/4/

Comment: That's good, but I don't want them to continue to expand. Also, the who 33.3% thing is a little risky considering the amount of images can always change.

Comment: You can set a max-width on the images to make sure they don't over-expand.  For the problem of a varying number of images you could either update the styles manually or come up with a more dynamic solution like the method I just added (querySelectorAll is not supported in IE < 8):